# What is the best way to deal with troll

Tags: discussion

Suddenly, about thirty of my answers were downvoted: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/458/sawa?tab=reputation.

It looks like it was done by [a single user](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/164/joshua-robison), given the fact that these consecutive downvotes were done right after the user gave [replies to my comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3104/fun-with-synonyms-eternity/3264#3264), and also that this user was awarded the Critic badge [image](given for first down vote) as well as the Suffrage badge [image](given for using 30 votes in a day) shortly after. (Very professional act as a teacher of English as Foreign Language in Osaka.)

I have already asked the moderator about this, but what is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: As a bonus, he's voted 30 times and all of them are downvotes.

Comment: All the related downvotes to my questions as well as the 30 downvotes made by Joshua Robison seem to have been deleted as Troyen suggests in the answer below, which further indicates that they were done by Joshua Robison. It is now resolved.

Comment: though 30 votes wouldn't even put a dent in your rep pool =P

Comment: Yes, this is a reprehensible behavior. However you might also want to watch your own attitude/comments/abusive downvotes towards other members of this community. Additionally, showing this person's picture in a post where you insult him is extremely rude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system will automatically detect and flag suspicious behavior like that.  So within 36 hours, those votes will be purged and your reputation will be automatically recalculated.  If you're worried about it you can also flag one of your posts for moderator attention and ask them to review any voting irregularities.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim/28758#28758/)

If he does it repeatedly for whatever reason, [his account would be subject to a suspension.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68262/can-the-anti-serial-downvoting-mechanism-revoke-the-suffrage-badge/68267#68267)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comment.

Comment: The downvotes disappeared. Thanks for the help.